# Exception in property when setting a binary value

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have the following method which gives me a stackoverflow exception on setting a value. I can't step into it and debug it application just crashes few seconds later. Here is the code

```
public byte[] ImageTIFF
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = ImageTIFFDir + ImageId + ".TIFF";

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return File.ReadAllBytes(ImageTIFFDir + ImageCollectionId + ".TIFF");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;        
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log("Can't read TIFF image from file.", e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            ImageTIFF = value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log("Can't set image TIFF.", e);
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

This gets called during an export and it fails on a first call:

```
someImage.ImageTIFF = File.ReadAllBytes(imageName);
```

Comment: Just noticed that filePath can be re-used in the return clause...This is not an issue though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to

```
private byte[] m_ImageTIFF;
public byte[] ImageTIFF 
{
  get{...}
  set { m_ImageTIFF = value;}
}
```

You need a backing store for the property.

Comment: Trying this out now. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

This is because , you are setting property itself in the set block

```
ImageTIFF = value;
```

make a `byte[]` array variable and set in the set block and in the get block return this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here you try to set value to the property you are already in.

```
try
{
    ImageTIFF = value;
}
```

You need to have class member behind that property. Something like

```
byte[] _imageTIFF
```

and set it

```
set
{
    try
    {
        _imageTIFF = value;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.log("Can't set image TIFF.", e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the value of Property within setting the value of the property...recursion, my friend:

```
ImageTIFF = value;
```

You'll need to create another variable to hole `value`. Properties are no variables, they're just wrappers.